# How long after posting 10 questions/answers does it take for my commitment to be fulfilled?

Tags: support, commitment

My understanding from the other similar questions is that you post 10 (questions + answers) and once the site goes public beta (if it isn't already), your commitment is fulfilled. I have [just posted 10 (questions + answers) on Statistical Analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/110/thomas-owens) so I could commit to my own proposal. But I still can't. When will I be able to commit to my own proposal?

Answer (score 2):

Should take less than 24 hours, but remember that deleted, closed, merged, etc posts aren't counted towards the total.

Sounds like you need to a wait a bit if you *just* fulfilled the requirement.

Comment: OK. That's cool. I wasn't sure if it was instantaneous or not. I'm just anxious to commit to my own proposal.